# Slack RTM API Connecting to Multiple Servers

Tags: ruby, websocket, slack-api, slack

I'm looking at creating a bot for Slack that can be installed across multiple different Slack communities. Slack offers a [Real Time Messaging (RTM)](https://api.slack.com/rtm) API that creates a web socket per community to manage. Are there any best practices in Ruby for connecting to multiple web sockets concurrently? Is this something EventMachine or Celluloid should be used for or do clients exist that allow connecting into multiple bots? Thanks!

Comment: I think the question could be clearer. Please help us help you by writing down your requirements a bit more clearly. As for the last part of your question, I think both [EventMachine](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-eventmachine-client) and [GRHttp](https://github.com/boazsegev/GRHttp) have reasonable WebSocket clients, both support multiple clients and both are designed around the reactor pattern. (GRHttp is a pure Ruby implementation while EM has external libraries). I'm partial and biased towards GRHttp.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a detailed post on "Writing a Slack Bot Service in Ruby": http://code.dblock.org/2015/11/14/writing-a-slack-bot-service-for-multiple-teams.html

You should use EventMachine or Celluloid. Either will work. A lot of the ground work has been done for you with a fully running sample in https://github.com/dblock/slack-bot-server.

**Update**: A more complete example can be found https://github.com/dblock/slack-gamebot which is the service that powers http://playplay.io, a Ping Pong, Chess and Pool Slack bot.